# error = ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this error with a spinner inside a fragment  = ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null , Does anyone know how to fix it ? , thanks in advance!﻿

Answer (score 1):

This happens when your fragment becomes detached from its activity. It happens sometimes because of screen rotation. I face same problem on Samsung Galaxy S4, when I opened the camera intent, my activity restarted due to screen orientation change. I fixed my problem by adding this line in my activity in the Manifest file:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```